# Is there any tools/script like "ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers", but can build ffmpeg for linux use?

Tags: ffmpeg

I found an corssbuild tools [ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers](https://github.com/rdp/ffmpeg-windows-build-helpers) , it's very useful, can build ffmpeg for windows with intel-qsv support.

Did anyone know any other tools/script can build ffmpeg for linux include intel-qsv support?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the "build scripts" I've come across are often outdated, just plain wrong, or blatant ripoffs of the various [compile guides on the FFmpeg Wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/#CompilingFFmpeg). You can easily script it yourself.

You did not mention your distro or provide any specifics, but your distro may have a ports like system with build scripts that you can modify. For example the [ffmpeg package from Arch Linux](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/plain/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/ffmpeg).

Answer (score 0):

The closest there is to what you're seeking would be [BtbN's ffmpeg builder](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds).

It's extremely flexible, and can build multiple flavors for supported platforms, ie Linux and Windows. See the [README.md](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds#readme) for how to get started with generating builds.